# How do I read my model stored inside a folder in EFS?

Tags: amazon-web-services, machine-learning, amazon-s3, aws-lambda, amazon-efs

I am trying to execute the https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/machine-learning/deploy-multiple-machine-learning-models-for-inference-on-aws-lambda-and-amazon-efs/  using my own model, currently I get the project API running, upload my model to the mount point in EFS and to S3 bucket.

Although I have done all the steps correctly following the AWS article, something is missing for me to be able to run my own model. Since the machine learning model that AWS used is part of EASYOCR, it is used the following line of code to read the EASYOCR model.

```
model_cache[languages_key] = easyocr.Reader(language_list, model_storage_directory=model_dir, user_network_directory=network_dir, gpu=False, download_enabled=False)
```

But since I want to use my own model it certainly won't work. The following code shows my inference code that is running separately in Lambda. So the goal would be to integrate this code into the ready-made AWS project.

```
from io import BytesIO
import threadpoolctl
import sklearn
import pickle
import boto3
import base64
import json
import joblib

s3_client = boto3.client('s3')

def lambda_handler(event, context):
    # getting bucket and object key from event object

    data = BytesIO()

    s3_client.download_fileobj(source_bucket, model_key, data)
    data.seek(0)    # move back to the beginning after writing
    load_model = pickle.loads(data.read())
    print("load_model", load_model)
    
    response = load_model.predict([[140000]])

    
    # Function Return 
    return {
        'statusCode': 200,
        'body': json.dumps(
            {
                "predicted_label": response,
            }
        )
    }
```

However, it doesn't make sense for me to replace inference code from AWS ([app.py](https://github.com/aws-samples/ml-inference-using-aws-lambda-and-amazon-efs/blob/main/ml-inference/app.py)) with my code that is running in Lambda. I know that my model is stored in the `/mnt/ml/models/` inside amazon EFS and the network directory is `/mnt/ml/network/`, but, I don't know how to use this information to read my model.

Would anyone have any suggestion, how I can read my model from Amazon EFS inside of the AWS inference function?

Comment: Hi @mariusz I have posted the answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To solve the problem I uploaded the model directly into the project, I created a new folder named `model`. To read this file I had to modify the code in the following way:

```
def lambda_handler(event, context):   
        # Make prediction
        response = []
        with open (os.path.join(model_dir, "models.pkl"), 'rb') as myfile:
            load_model = pickle.load(myfile)
            y_pred = load_model.predict([[14000]])
            y_est = str(np.around(y_pred[0], decimals=2))
            response.append(y_est)

    except Exception as e:
        print(e)
        response = ["Error"]
        
    # Function Return 
    return {
        'statusCode': 200,
        'body': json.dumps(
            {
                "response": response[0],
            }
        )
    }
```

Inside dockerfile it's need to copy the folder into docker, to do this, I used the command line `COPY model/ ./model`.